# Filter by multiple items in lists?

Tags: python-polars

Given a DataFrame with a list column and a list of items not in the data frame, is there an efficient way to filter the table to only have rows where the list column value contains a) one of the items in the list and b) all of the items in the list?

Comment: Hi Brian, for the first case you can use Expr.is_in (). You can check the example in the doc and replace select with filter https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_in.html#polars.Expr.is_in

Comment: For the second case, one solution would be doing an explode, checking if it’s contained, then doing a groupby and using pl.all to verify if all the items were contained in the list

Comment: Thanks, Luca! Regarding `is_in`, can it work with a list external to the data frame? I guess I can do an explode/regroup for both of these too.

Comment: I think I'm still stuck. I can't `pl.lit([1,2,3]).is_in(...)` and I also can't `df.explode('sets').filter(pl.col('sets') in [1,2])`

Comment: Looks like there is a good solution from @Wayoshi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass multiple tests to the [`any/all` horizontal functions](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.any_horizontal.html#polars.all_horizontal):

- `.all_horizontal()`

```py
items = 1, 2

df.filter(
   pl.all_horizontal(
      pl.lit(item).is_in(pl.col("sets")) for item in items
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ sets      │
│ ---       │
│ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] │
│ [2, 0, 1] │
└───────────┘
```

<sup>(**note:** `.filter` now accepts `*args` syntax, which can replace `.all_horizontal`)</sup>

- `any_horizontal()`

```py
df.filter(
   pl.any_horizontal(
      pl.lit(item).is_in(pl.col("sets")) for item in items
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (6, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ sets      │
│ ---       │
│ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] │
│ [2, 12]   │
│ [6, 6, 1] │
│ [2, 0, 1] │
│ [1, 1, 4] │
│ [2, 7, 2] │
└───────────┘
```

dataframe used:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"sets": [
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4],
   [9, 10],
   [2, 12],
   [6, 6, 1],
   [2, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 4],
   [2, 7, 2]]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that's much cleaner! I didn't realize a list comprehension was possible there

Answer (score 1):

Given the following df (expanded upon one given in Discord):

```
>>> df
shape: (8, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ sets      │
│ ---       │
│ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] │
│ [4]       │
│ [9, 10]   │
│ [2, 12]   │
│ [6, 6, 1] │
│ [2, 0, 1] │
│ [1, 1, 4] │
│ [2, 7, 2] │
└───────────┘
```

For `any`, the aforementioned `arr.explode`, `is_in` and a group by works quite well. A unique row identifier is needed to correctly groupby here, I believe - that's exactly what `with_row_count` is for. Then an `over` expression to do the groupby and by-group (by-row) calculation in-place:

```
>>> items = [1, 2]
>>> df.with_row_count().filter(
    pl.col('sets').arr.explode()
    .is_in(items)
    .any()
    .over('row_nr')
)
shape: (6, 2)
┌────────┬───────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ sets      │
│ ---    ┆ ---       │
│ u32    ┆ list[i64] │
╞════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ [1, 2, 3] │
│ 3      ┆ [2, 12]   │
│ 4      ┆ [6, 6, 1] │
│ 5      ┆ [2, 0, 1] │
│ 6      ┆ [1, 1, 4] │
│ 7      ┆ [2, 7, 2] │
└────────┴───────────┘
# can drop the row_nr column now whenever
```

The `all` can be broken down like this: If these are real sets with no repeated value on a row, it is efficiently solvable by summing up the Trues (1) and Falses (0) within each group and checking the sum against the length of the items. Therefore, we can ensure a real set with a `unique`. This can be done either as `arr.unique().arr.explode()` or `arr.explode().unique()`.

```
>>> len_items = len(items)
>>> df.with_row_count().filter(
    pl.col('sets').arr.explode()
    .unique()
    .is_in(items)
    .sum()
    .over('row_nr') == len_items
)
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────┬───────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ sets      │
│ ---    ┆ ---       │
│ u32    ┆ list[i64] │
╞════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ [1, 2, 3] │
│ 5      ┆ [2, 0, 1] │
└────────┴───────────┘
```

(Note the `any` case matches up with `> 0` as the condition, if you want to cache this column to do both types of filters.)

Comment: Thank you! This is more complicated than I expected would be needed